# Knockout, entity framework and html5

Tags: jquery, json, html, entity-framework, knockout.js

I'm a little new to working with JSON and Html5.  My goal is to use my existing EF and put together a page that traverses through the results from EF using Knockout, HTML5 and JSON.

The first issue I would appear to have is the sequence thats returned in JSON.  It does appear as i would have expected or like the EF displays it.

```
    [
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Scott",
    "LastName": "White",
    "Email": "scott.white@test.com",
    "Department": "IT",
    "Assistant": "",
    "Contacts": [
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "Person1": {
          "$id": "3",
          "Contacts": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            }
          ],
          "Notes": [
            {
              "$id": "4",
              "Person1": {
                "$ref": "3"
              },
              "Id": 1,
              "Person": 1,
              "Note1": "Testing notes"
            }
          ],
          "Office1": {
            "$id": "5",
            "People": [
              {
                "$ref": "3"
              }
            ],
            "Id": 1,
            "ShortCode": "CDF",
            "OfficeName": "Cardiff",
            "Address": "my House, my Place, Cardiff",
            "Postcode": "CF10 3AA",
            "Telephone": "029 2000 0000",
            "Fax": "029 2000 0000",
            "Dx": "300000 Cardiff 1",
            "Floor": "0, 1, 2, 3",
            "Equipment": "2 x OHP, 1 x Screen, 1 x Video Camera,2 x Flip Charts"
          },
          "Id": 1,
          "FirstName": "Scott",
          "LastName": "White",
          "Email": "scott.white@test.com",
          "Department": "IT",
          "Office": 1,
          "Assistant": ""
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "Person": 1,
        "Number": "02920 000011",
        "NumberType": "Business"
      }
    ],
    "Notes": [
      {
        "$ref": "4"
      }
    ],
    "Office1": {
      "$ref": "5"
    }
  }
]
```

So I'm trying to traverse this like so (sooo new to this). I've setup a MVVM as such

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function PersonsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.loaded = ko.observable(false);
            self.persons = ko.observableArray([]);

            // Load the initial state
            $.getJSON("api/person", self.persons)
                .done(function () { self.loaded(true); });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new PersonsViewModel());
        })

    </script>
```

And the HTML 5 data bind like so

```
<ul id="persons" data-bind="foreach: persons">
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <div>
                    <span data-bind="text: FirstName || 'FirstName?'"></span>&nbsp;
                    <span data-bind="text: LastName || 'LastName?'"></span>
                </div>

                <ul data-bind="foreach: Contacts">

                    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <div>
                            Test<span data-bind="text: OfficeName || 'OfficeName?'"></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <a data-bind="visible: Email,
                          text: Email,
                          attr: { href: 'mailto:' + Email }"></a>
                    <span data-bind="visible: !Email">Email?</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The only result I seem to get out is the FirstName and LastName.  I don't really know how to traverse the structure correctly and as aforementioned it appears a little odd anyhow.  I've parsed the JSON in jsfiddle.  Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks in advance 
Scott

Comment: I don't see where you're assigning the JSON values to the KO bound members.  Can you provide that code?  For instance, I see you instantiate/declare 'persons' as a new array, but you haven't provided the code where you push members to the array.

Comment: Hi Justin,  thanks for your comments.  I'm using the .net ApiController so the return from EF is pushing this to the array when it does $.getJSON("api/person", self.persons)
                .done(function () { self.loaded(true); });  The call itself is in the .net controller and is a simple public IEnumerable<PersonDto> Get() { return mytasks.GetAllPersons(); }.  As I've mentioned to beau, I didn't quite understand how the Json formatter was taking my response from the controller and why it's appending 1 to the objects.  This i'm working out now.

Comment: See my answer, and the other answer by 'sroes'.  The answer is not the one you voted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're doing wrong.

You are using the 'getJSON' jQuery function inappropriately in regards to assigning your JSON to a ko.observable.  To assign to a ko.observable, you need to pass in the value, not assign it using an '=' operator.  In your case, what you are thinking the return results will simply assign themselves to self.persons by placing 'self.persons' in the second argument of your $.getJSON function call.  This doesn't work from a javascript rules perspective or a KnockoutJS perspective.

For one, you cannot use an existing variable to capture arguments in the method call of a function.  These are declared and scoped to the function call.

Secondly, KnockoutJS assignments for arrays are completed as such, `ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.persons, json);`

Rewrite your code to handle it as such...

```
        $.getJSON("api/person")
            .done(function (json) {
                ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.persons, json);
                self.loaded(true); 
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are populating `persons` is wrong. Try the following:

```
        $.getJSON("api/person").done(function (persons) {
            ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.persons, persons);
            self.loaded(true); 
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

In your view model, the first object within Contacts you have named 'Person1'. I'd restructure this, but to get 'OfficeName' you would need to

```
data-bind="Person1.Office1.OfficeName"
```

One suggestion for your restructure would be

```
{ ..., Contacts: [ id: XXX, Person: { ..., Notes: [ ... ], Office: { ... } } ] }
```

Remember, when your running a foreach binding, your context becomes the instance of the object within the objects you are looping through.

Comment: Thanks beauXjames I appreciate your help.  With regards to the structure I need to look at this further.  To be honest I wasn't expecting this structure from the entity.  It appears the Json serializer (Newtonsoft) is appending the 1 to the object names!  Again thanks. S

Comment: This is not the answer.  Look at the other answer by user 'sroes', and the more detailed explanation by myself.  They concur and are correct.

Comment: As there are better ways of using the jQuery methods of attaining the data (as @JustinRusso points out) your model needs to undergo a bit of scrutiny. The real learning lesson, in terms of Knockout, is a better understanding of optimizing the model itself so you understand the context...which is where the problem really lies. You've proven your ajax call works in that you get the name of the first person at all.

Comment: After reading all comments, i can now see what i'm doing wrong and yes the model needs to be defined a little more.  I was working with previously made EF hoping to not have to do much to each dto.  I can work on this now i have a better understanding of how jquery/knockout is pushing the data out.  Thanks all.  Really appreciate your comments and help.